# The correct meaning for '要多讽刺就有多讽刺'

Tags: meaning-in-context

“最具社会责任教育家”开除患癌教师，要多讽刺就有多讽刺

Does '要多讽刺就有多讽刺' here mean 'you have to be as ironic as you need to be' (which i think quite weird here, but i'm not sure) or does it mean 'it's very ironic'?

Comment: 要多＋adjective＋(就)有多    the most +adjective+ imaginable (you could imagine) e.g.要多荒唐有多荒唐

jukuu： looking as foolish as he could do：显得要多蠢就有多蠢。Abraham Lincoln: Most people are about as happy as they make up their minds to be. 一个人打算要有多快乐，他就有多快乐

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "as ironic as you could imagine". It implies to the largest extent (as you could possibly imagine) .

Comment: Is phrase structure '要多__就有多__' often used?

Comment: Yeah, that's the case I gather. I could get more of these off the top of my head: 要多 久 就有多 久， 要多 长 就有多 长， 要多 漂亮 就有多 漂亮。 It seems it works for all kinds of descriptive words, like 好，坏，美， 年轻，老，痛, ..... ....

Answer (score 1):

It's much more ironical that **the most social responsible educator** dismiss the cancerous teacher.

你要多少有多少
Literally: How many you want, so many there are.
You can get as more as you want.

宇宙要多大有多大
Literally: How large is the universe you can imagine, so large it would be.
The universe is as large as can imagine.